# Open docx file from resource using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app that uses docx files. They are stored in res/raw. I'm trying to open them using this code:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"  + R.raw.ampenadas);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String type = "application/*";
        intent.setDataAndType(path, type);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And I get this error:

```
04-18 10:32:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(17359): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.barvaz.recipes/2131034113 typ=application/* flg=0x10000000 }
```

I have an application that can open docx files and I have no problem opening the files from outside the app.

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to mention which ACTIVITY is going to handle the intent before starting it(before this line **startActivity(intent)**).

Please look over code in point number 1(Build an intent) in this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Like this the blocked one,

Intent intent = new Intent(**this, DisplayMessageActivity.class**);

Comment: The activity that will handle the intent is an outside activity, like when opening a pdf file. That's why I'm using setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)